# Detecting whether sprite is outside the camera's view

Tags: unity, sprites, transformation

I want to detect when the game object is not visible anymore.

I search for the size of the `SpriteRenderer`, and convert it to screen space. Then, I check if the position is below or above a certain `yMin` or `Ymax`, defined as:

```
yMin = - mySprite.y;
yMax = cam.pixelHeight + mySprite.y;
```

But it does not work at all!

Besides that, I attempted to print the size of the `SpriteRenderer`'s bounding rectangle, and it is too big for the actual sprite. See the image below.

The actual code to display the rectangle :

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    Vector3 position = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector2 bounds = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(mySprite.bounds.size);
    DrawQuad(new Rect(position.x, cam.pixelHeight - position.y, bounds.x, bounds.y), Color.green);
}

void DrawQuad(Rect position, Color color)
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
    texture.Apply();
    GUI.skin.box.normal.background = texture;
    GUI.Box(position, GUIContent.none);
}
```

When I print the size of the Sprite in the Log I get: `420.12, 280.22, 10.0`, but the size of the image is 446*520.

I would like to understand the magic behind this.

[image: sprite renderer size]

Comment: Have you considered using [OnBecameInvisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
Vector2 bounds = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(mySprite.bounds.size);
```

As the function name says, it gives you a point: a specific location in space, not a dimension. To understand how this fails, imagine we pass the size (2, 5) before and after moving the camera: because the camera has shifted, the point (2, 5) will correspond to a different position on the screen before and after the move, and so we'll get two different values, even though the bounds we passed did not change.

Instead, you can compute the scaling factor of an orthographic camera (taking into account that `orthographicSize` is half the camera's world space height), and use that to convert world space bounds into screen space:

```
float pixelsPerUnit = cam.pixelHeight / (2f * cam.orthographicSize);
float screenSpaceSize = mySprite.bounds.size * pixelsPerUnit;
```

Though I think it would be even clearer to write your code something like this:

```cs
bool IsOffScreenVertically(SpriteRenderer sprite, Camera camera) {
    var bounds = sprite.bounds;

    var top = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(bounds.max);
    var bottom = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(bounds.min);

    return top.y < 0 || bottom.y > 1;    
}
```

Here we're using viewport coordinates, where (0, 0) is the bottom-left corner of the camera's viewport and (1, 1) is the top-right, so there's no need for pixel conversions at all. And we're using points throughout, not lengths/sizes, so we don't need to go outside the available named functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will try this today. (I can't upvote your answer because I'm new)
What's the purpose of WorldToScreenPoint then ? Why there is not any function to convert to ScreenSpace ? Thank you again, this drove my crazy

Comment: There is a function to convert positions to screen space, that's `WorldToScreenPoint`. Your problem was you were using it to try to transform a *length*, not a position. This function is great for doing things that specifically need pixel coordinates: like say you want to select and drag an object in the world with a mouse cursor that's in screen space, with a little snapping assistance measured as a pixel radius. That's a case it would help with. For just knowing whether an object is above/below the screen, you don't care how many pixels are on the screen, so you have simpler options.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation, I use the suggested code and it works perfectly.